# Fix mixed encoding in string

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a file which contains the following string:

```
AAdοbe Dοcument Clοud
```

if viewed in Notepad++. In hex view the string looks like this:

[image]

If I read the file with Java the string looks like this:

```
AAdÎ¿be DÎ¿cument ClÎ¿ud
```

How I can get the same encoding in Java as with Notepad++?

Comment: How are you reading it in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is encoded as UTF-8, and the `CE BF` bytes is the UTF-8 encoding of the character `ο` (['GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON' (U+03BF)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bf/index.htm)).

If you use the `Encoding` pull-down menu in Notepad++ to specify UTF-8, you should see the content as:

```
AAdοbe Dοcument Clοud
```

You might want to replace those Greek ο's with regular Latin o's (['LATIN SMALL LETTER O' (U+006F)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006f/index.htm)).

If you decide to keep the Greek ο's, you need to make sure your Java program reads the file using UTF-8, which is best done using one of these:

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt")); // UTF-8 is the default

BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

If you look at the text with a debugger, you should see that it is now read correctly. If you print the text, make sure the console window you're using can handle UTF-8 characters, otherwise it might just print wrong, even though it was read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must set encoding in file reader ilke this.

```
new FileReader(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: I tried this but does not help, still have AAdÎ¿be DÎ¿cument ClÎ¿ud

Comment: What an encoding of your file?

Comment: *FYI for others:* The constructor used here was added in Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the file in java using the same encoding as the file has.

If you are working with non standard encodings, even trying to read the encoding with something like:

```
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(theFile));
r.getEncoding()
```

Can output with wrong values.

There's little library which handles recognition of encoding a bit better: https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/
It also has some holes in obtaining proper encoding, but I've used it.
And while using it I found out that most of non-standard encodings can be read with UTF-16 like:

```
new FileReader(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_16)
```

Since a while, Java supports usage of UTF-16 encoding. It's defined in Java standard API as `StandardCharsets.UTF_16`. That character set covers lots of language specific characters and emojis.